# Socket object is not same between server and client

Tags: java, sockets

Are there any ways to check if the same Socket is used between the server-side and client-side?

- What I did.

1. Create DateServer.java and DateClient.java
2. Run DateServer.java
3. Run DateClient.java
4. Check both hashCode on the console. The hashCode is different. I thought it was the same.

- DateServer.java

```java
package net;
    
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Date;

public class DateServer {
    
    public static final int LISTENING_PORT = 32007;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ServerSocket listener;
        Socket connection;
        try {
            listener = new ServerSocket(LISTENING_PORT);
    
            while (true) {
                connection = listener.accept();
                System.out.println(connection.hashCode());
                
                sendDate(connection);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return;
        }
    }
    
    private static void sendDate(Socket client) {
        try {
            Date now = new Date();
            PrintWriter outgoing = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream());
            outgoing.println(now.toString());
            outgoing.flush();
            client.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

- DateClient.java

```java
package net;
    
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.Socket;
    
public class DateClient {
    
    public static final int LISTENING_PORT = 32007;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        String hostName = "localhost";
        Socket connection;
        BufferedReader incoming;
    
        try {
            connection = new Socket(hostName, LISTENING_PORT);
            System.out.println(connection.hashCode());
                
            incoming = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            String lineFromServer = incoming.readLine();
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println(lineFromServer);
            System.out.println();
            incoming.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

- Output on server side.

  1804094807
- Output on client side.

  1826771953

  Sun Mar 07 18:16:05 JST 2021

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already stated by Steffen, the hashcodes of the server-side and client-side sockets is just based on the memory address of the two objects in two different JVMs.

What **will** be `equal` is:

- `connection.getLocalSocketAddress()` of the client
- `connection.getRemoteSocketAddres()` of the server

and viceversa. That includes the result of the `hashCode()` and `toString()` methods, since [`InetSockeAddress`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetSocketAddress.html) overrides all three `equals`, `hashCode` and `toString` methods.

Answer (score 1):

> The hashCode is different. I thought it was the same

This assumption is wrong. And I don't know where it comes from. But `hashCode` just returns a **local** identifier associated with a **local** object.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on hashcode implementation, as you can see in case of Socket the hashcode is unique to the instance that was created within that process.

**Please take a look on this example**

Hashcode is the same only because It is driven by state of Person, and we had to implement It. However the identity hashcode of person objects differ.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    class Person {
        private int age;
        private int cash;

        public Person(int age, int cash) {
            this.age = age;
            this.cash = cash;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return (31 * age) + cash;
        }

        public int defaultHashCodeImplementation() {
            return super.hashCode();
        }
    }

    Person p1 = new Person(30, 100);
    System.out.println("p1 hashcode: " + p1.hashCode());
    System.out.println("p1 identity hashcode: " + p1.defaultHashCodeImplementation());

    Person p2 = new Person(30, 100);
    System.out.println("p2 hashcode: " + p2.hashCode());
    System.out.println("p2 identity hashcode: " + p2.defaultHashCodeImplementation());
}
```

Output

```
p1 hashcode: 1030
p1 object identity hashcode: 1712669532
p2 hashcode: 1030
p2 object identity hashcode: 1225373914
```